# Vuex - axios Post gives different errors

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js, vuex

I'm trying to POST a list to the server and expecting it to return Filtered data from server.
I have two components. In the first component, I have one button. When I click it, it sends a request to the server and makes second component visible  below the button. In the second component, there is a v-datatable. In the second component, I am trying to access the list returned from server but it gives error.

[image: Some Of the Errors when I click the BUTTON]

Component-1

```
...
<v-btn
     class="ma-2"
     outlined
     color="red"
     @click="SET_HANDLER()">LIST()
</v-btn>
</v-row>
      </v-container>      
  </v-form>
    <SecondComponentDataTable v-if="showDT==true"></SecondComponentDataTable>
</div>
```

Script Part:

```
<script>
  import axios from 'axios'
  import SecondComponentDataTable from '@/components/SecondComponentDataTable'

export default {
    components:{
        SecondComponentDataTable 
    },
    methods:{
        SET_HANDLER()
        {
            this.showDT=true;
            this.$store.dispatch('getPosts',this.entity)
        },
```

SecondComponentDataTable:

```
<template>
  <v-data-table
            :items="inspection"
         ...
<script>
  import {  mapState } from "vuex";

export default {    
    
    computed:mapState([
        'inspection'
    ]),   
}
</script>
```

I would like to mention that, I have never encountered an error before seperating Store files.

This is the inspectionReview.js Storefile located store/modules/

```
import axios from 'axios'

const state={
    inspection:[]    
}

const actions = {
    getPosts ({ commit },payload) {
        axios.post('https://localhost:44377/Dossier/GetFiltered',payload)
            .then(r => r.data)
            .then(inspection=> {
            commit('SET_FILTERED', inspection)
          })
      }    
}
const mutations = 
{    
    SET_FILTERED(state, inspection) {
        state.inspection= inspection;
      },
}
export default {
    state,
    actions,
    mutations,
    
  }
```

This is the Index.js (general Store file) located store/index.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import axios from 'axios'
import inspectionReview from "./modules/inspectionReview";

Vue.use(Vuex)

export default new Vuex.Store({
  state: { 
    }, 
  
    mutations: {
     
  },
  actions: {
    
  },
  modules: {
    inspectionReview
  }
})
```

The inspection list looks like :

```
"id": "3fa85f64-5717-4562-b3fc-2c963f66afa6",
  "openingTypeId": 0,
  "sourceId": 0,
  "institutionTypeId": 0,
  "resultId": 0,
  "linkedUnit": "string",
  "linkedUnitId": 0,
  "complaintSubjectId": 0,
  "dossierYearId": 0,
  "dossierNumber": "string",
  "dossierName": "string",
  "cityId": 0,
  "description": "string",
  "createdAt": "2021-07-29T08:22:56.642Z",
  "createdBy": "string",
  "modifiedAt": "2021-07-29T08:22:56.642Z",
  "modifiedBy": "string",
  "deletedAt": "2021-07-29T08:22:56.642Z",
  "deletedBy": "string",
  "isInUse": true
}
```

Comment: Can you please post the response data from the server as well.

Comment: You are missing the module name here: `this.$store.dispatch('getPosts',this.entity)` (should read `this.$store.dispatch('inspectionReview/getPosts',this.entity)`)

Comment: @slauth getPosts method actually works without changing the line that you typed. But again I change the line and gives error : [vuex] unknown action type: inspectionReview/getPosts . This time getPosts method doesn't called.

Comment: @user3718908 okay I posted it

Comment: @veli okay so now I'm a bit confused because you posted a json object not an array.

Comment: @veli you are right, my suggestion only applies when using [namespaced](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/modules.html#namespacing) modules.

Comment: @veli From your JSON response it seems you are trying to loop over an object instead of an array of items hence your error.

Comment: @user3718908 but when I delete inspectionReview.js file and move the actions,mutations etc. to the store/index.js file. I don't encounter any error. These errors occurs only when I use seperate Store files..

Comment: what does the LIST() do on component 1 @click property?

Comment: amachi malet nw...

Comment: @veli No matter where your code is as long as the response from the server is an object like you posted your code should not work.  So if you didn't post the actual or full JSON response I suggest you do will make it easier to find a solution for your issue.